# Can this line integral problem be solved with Stokes theorem?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I have a feeling it could, or with some other theorem.

$F(x,y,z) = (2xyz + \sin x)i + (x^2z)j + (x^2y)k$

$$\int_{c} F.ds$$ where $c(t) = (\cos^5(t),\sin^3(t),t^4)$

I tried it in differential form as follows, but I am getting an integral that seems way to hard. I put it in differential form and got this:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} 10\cos^9(t)\sin^4(t)t^4 + 5\cos^4(t)\sin(t)\sin(\cos^5(t)) + \cos^{10}(t)t^4(3\sin^2(t)) + \cdots $$

There is no way there isn't an easier way to solve this problem. Stokes theorem, Greens theorem. Something?

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, by stokes theorem, the integral is equivalent to:

$\int_R(\nabla\times F)\cdot n dA$, where I believe $R$ is the region enclosed by $c$.

But we see that $\nabla\times F=0$, so the integral is zero.

$\nabla\times F=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\underline{i} & \underline{j} & \underline{k} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
2xyz+\sin(x) & x^2z & x^2y \end{array} \right|=(x^2-x^2,2xy-2xy,2xz-2xz)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: Thank you so much. For future reference. How do I check to see if the curve is simply connected or applicable to use greens theorem or stokes theorem? I couldn't even visualize the vector field or what the curve even looked like. From the looks of it, I thought it was a helix.

Comment: $c(t)$ is a closed space curve for $-2\pi \leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi$

Comment: @M.Strochyk
Does that mean it would enclose some surface?

Comment: @ellya Yes. I was mistaken in the previous comment: $c(t)$ is closed for $-\pi \leqslant t \leqslant \pi \ .$

Comment: @M.Strochyk but not for $0\le t\le 2\pi$?

Comment: @ellya Denote $x(t)=\cos^5{t}, \;\; y(t)=\sin^3{t},\;\;z(t)=t^4.$ Then $z(0)=0\ne z(2\pi)=\pi^4.$

Comment: @ellya  
However, $c(-\pi)=(-1,\; 0,\; (-\pi)^4 )=(-1,\; 0,\; \pi^4 )=c(\pi).$